# reading lines from text file in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

Im trying to read .txt file that contains several similar entities (see below). The tag that indicates the instance of the object to be created is "TYPE". I need to  make this work for all possible sequenceses. Is there a way that will allow me to read the file line by line until I find the "TYPE" tag and then to go back at the begining of the entity so as to read the other lines?

```
 CONTRACT_LIST
 {
 CONTRACT
 {
 TIME_SPENT ***********
 TYPE *************
 .
 .
 .
 .
 PAYMENT_METHOD ***
 DISCOUNT *****
 }
 }
```

Im using a FileReader in a BufferedReader. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrong approach completely. You need to *parse* the input left to right. Your way is monstrously inefficient.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for your tip. How is this done?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8, you can use [Files.readAllLines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-)

eg.:

```
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file.txt"), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    for(String line : lines) {
        if(line.contains("TYPE")) {
            //Do your Thing
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could store all in a list like that
`

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
String line;
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yourInputstream));
line= buffer.readLine();
l.add(line);

while (line!=null && !line.equals("TYPE")){

    line= buffer.readLine();
    l.add(line);
}
```

` 
no guarantee that it works(very tired  ༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ)